# Vim Scripting - call function once for all selected lines

Tags: vim

So I have a text file like this:

```
Item a: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
```

I'd like to replace `<total>` with the total of 10 and 20. Right now I'm doing it with the following functions:

```
let g:S = 0  "result in global variable S
function! Sum(number)
  let g:S = g:S + a:number
  return a:number
endfunction

function! SumSelection()
  let g:S=0
  '<,'>s/\d\+/\=Sum(submatch(0))/g
  echo g:S
endfunction

vnoremap <s-e> call SumSelection()<cr>
```

`Sum` gets the sum of numbers passed in, `SumSelection` calls sum over all the numbers in selected lines, and (supposedly) Shift+e calls SumSelection in visual mode (or whatever you choose to call it.)

Problem is, when I hit Shift+e when I have some lines selected, instead of `:call SumSelection()` I really get `:'<,'>call SumSelection()` which means the function gets called once per selected line. No good, right? So as far as I can tell there's no way around this. What can I do to get the function to:

1. be only called once
2. maybe total these in a more efficient way

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, to have a function execute just once over a range, append the `range` keyword. E.g.

```
fun Foo() range
    ...
endfun
```

Then your function can take care of the range itself with the special parameters a:firstline
and a:lastline. (See `:help a:firstline` for details.)

However I think that in this case your requirements are just about simple enough to be accomplished with
a one-liner using `:global`.

We could do with better specified inputs and outputs really. But assuming a file containing

```
Item a: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
Item b: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
Item c: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
  Subitem 3: 43 min
```

and a function defined as

```
fun! Sum(n)
    let g:s += a:n
    return a:n
endfun
```

then this will sum the subitems (all one line)

`:g/^Item/ let g:s = 0 | mark a | +,-/\nItem\|\%$/ s/\v(\d+)\ze\s+min$/\=Sum(submatch(0))/g | 'a s/<total>/\=(g:s . ' min')/`

and produce this output

```
Item a: 30 min
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
Item b: 33 min
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
Item c: 76 min
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
  Subitem 3: 43 min
```

By the way, the above command acts on the whole buffer. If you highlight a range first and then hit the `:` key, vim will automatically prepend your command with `'<,'>` meaning that the following command will operate from the start to the end of the highlighted range.

E.g. highlighting lines 1 to 5 and then running the command (`:'<,'> g/...`) produces this output

```
Item a: 30 min
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
Item b: 33 min
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
Item c: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
  Subitem 3: 43 min
```

One final note. If one of the groups has no subitems, e.g.

```
Item a: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
Item b: <total>
Item c: <total>
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
  Subitem 3: 43 min
```

then the command will abort with an 'Invalid range' error when it reaches the second item. You can get Vim to ignore this
and carry on regardless by prefixing the whole command with `:silent!`.

**EDIT**

Just a quick explanation of my workflow and why the long one-liner.

1. I like `:g` and ex commands a lot.
2. I built up the command interactively using the command-line history and the command-line window for editing.
3. When I'm done I paste one-off commands like this into the buffer: I have a mapping to execute the current line as an ex command. That way the command is always easily available when I need it. For more regular use you might want a command, function, or a ftplugin.

Comment: it's... beautiful... Seriously, thanks for the best SO answer I've probably ever received.

Comment: Btw, for anyone who thinks that the :g command above looks complex, it isn't really. The syntax is very terse which might give it that appearance, but the operations are really quite straightforward; there aren't any clever tricks. Just look up the bits you don't get in the wonderful documentation, or ask on SO or the vim_use Google group.

Comment: It took me a long time to understand... so here is an explanation:

:g  starts a global command
/^Item/  The command runs at each line that matches ^Item

let g:s = 0

mark a
Stores the position of cursor in a

+,-/\nItem\|\%$/s/\v(\d+)\ze\s+min$/\=Sum(submatch(0))/g
This is a massive beast of a substitute command. The part until the first 's' is the range, the part between the 's' and the '$' is the pattern and the function call is the replacement (nothing is actually replaced)

'a
go back to the position marked a

s/<total>/\=(g:s . ' min')/
finally replace the <total>

Comment: 'nothing is actually replaced'. Yep, that's the key calling out to code from within regexps in Vim.

Comment: I don't understand what the `-` is needed for in the range specification in front of the `/\nItem\|\%$/`.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger That was just a bit of defensive programming in case you have an empty group, otherwise you'd get the total of the subsequent group.

Comment: @1983, ok,but I don't understand what it *does*.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger It starts the search one line back from the current line.

Answer (score 1):

I know my `vim7.3-script` is much longer than `adscriven`'s.
But it can get the job done.

```
fun! SubTotal()
    fun! Collect()
        " define some global vars
        if line('.') == 1
            let g:dict = {}
            let g:key = ''
        endif

        " set current key && add key to dict
        fun! AddKey(k)
            let g:key = a:k
            let g:dict[a:k]= []
        endfun

        " add value to dict[key]
        fun! AddValue(v)
            if g:key != ''
                call add(g:dict[g:key], a:v)
            endif
        endfun

        " scan every line
        let line = getline('.')
        if line =~ '^Item'
            call AddKey(matchstr(line, '^Item\s\+\zs\w\+\ze\s*:'))
        elseif line =~ '^\s*Subitem'
            call AddValue(str2nr(matchstr(line, '\d\+\ze\s*min$')))
        endif
        return line
    endfun

    " collect data line by line
    silent %s/.*/\=Collect()/
    " replace <total> with sum
    silent g/^Item/s/^Item\s\+\(\w\+\)\s*:\s*\zs.*/\=eval(join(g:dict[submatch(1)], '+'))/
endfun
```

---

```
Item a: 30
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 20 min
Item b: 33
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
Item c: 76
  Subitem: 10 min
  Subitem 2: 23 min
  Subitem 3: 43 min
```

---

```
:echo dict
{'a': [10, 20], 'b': [10, 23], 'c': [10, 23, 43]}
```